# Node.js / Javascript - Wait until method is finished

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, methods, wait

I'm writing a steam trade bot but I have the problem that the for-loop doesn't wait until the method which is inside the for-loop is finished. So the code doesn't work as it should.

```
for (i = 0; i < offer.itemsToReceive.length; i++) {

    console.log(offer.itemsToReceive[i].market_hash_name);

    community.getMarketItem(appid.CSGO, offer.itemsToReceive[i].market_hash_name, function(err, items) {
        if (err) {
            Winston.error("Error getting Marketprice");
        } else {
            var cacheItemPrice = items.lowestPrice;
            totalValue += items.lowestPrice;
            Winston.info("Item " + offer.itemsToReceive[i].market_hash_name + " is " + items.lowestPrice + " Cents worth");
            if (items.lowestPrice <= minValue) {
                minValue = items.lowestPrice;
            }
        }

    });
}
```

If the loop doesn't wait until the method is finished, the variable `i` isn't correct in the method and I get a wrong result.

**Edit**:
Now when I put the code from @Cleiton into my function from which I want to return two values, the function returns the value before the method has time to change the them.

```
function checkItemPricesCashIn(offer) {
    Winston.info("Getting itemprices from trade #" + offer.id);
    var totalValue = 0;
    var minValue = 50;

    var executionList = [];

    function getMarketItem(item) {
        var market_hash_name = item.market_hash_name;
        return function() {
            community.getMarketItem(appid.CSGO, market_hash_name, function(err, items) {
                if (err) {
                    Winston.error("Error getting Marketprice");
                } else {
                    var cacheItemPrice = items.lowestPrice;
                    totalValue += items.lowestPrice;
                    Winston.info("Item " + market_hash_name + " is " + items.lowestPrice + " Cents worth");
                    if (items.lowestPrice <= minValue) {
                        minValue = items.lowestPrice;
                    }
                } 
                (executionList.shift() || function() {})();
            });
        }
    }

    offer.itemsToReceive.forEach(function(item) {
        executionList.push(getMarketItem(item));
    });

    if (executionList.length) {
        executionList.shift()();
    }

    console.log(totalValue);
    console.log(minValue);

    return {
        totalValue: totalValue,
        minValue: minValue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a complete working code, I hope this helps :)

```js
function checkItemPricesCashIn(offer, cb) {
Winston.info("Getting itemprices from trade #" + offer.id);
var totalValue = 0;
var minValue = 50;

var executionList = [];

function getMarketItem(item) {
    var market_hash_name = item.market_hash_name;
    return function() {
        community.getMarketItem(appid.CSGO, market_hash_name, function(err, items) {
            if (err) {
                Winston.error("Error getting Marketprice");
            } else {
                var cacheItemPrice = items.lowestPrice;
                totalValue += items.lowestPrice;
                Winston.info("Item " + market_hash_name + " is " + items.lowestPrice + " Cents worth");
                if (items.lowestPrice <= minValue) {
                    minValue = items.lowestPrice;
                }
            } 
            (executionList.shift() || cb)(minValue,totalValue);
        });
    }
}

offer.itemsToReceive.forEach(function(item) {
    executionList.push(getMarketItem(item));
});

if (executionList.length) {
    executionList.shift()();
}
}
```

How to use:

```
checkItemPricesCashIn(yourOffer/*your offer*/, function(min, max){
//it will be execute just after
console.log('min', min);
console.log('max', max);

});
```

Comment: Thanks for this code. But now when I put this code into my function which returns the total value and the minimum value, the function returns the values before the method can change them. See edit above...

Answer (score 1):

You could use some library as async https://github.com/caolan/async. And with it any async cycle as eachSeries or just each.

```js
async.each(array, function(item, callback){
    // do something with a item
    // call callback when finished
    callback();
});
```